# import org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I have just upgraded to Netbeans 7.3 and cannot import

```
org.openide.filesystems.FileUtil;
```

I get the message `org.openide.filesystms` does not exist.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is documented in [this netbeans's bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189329)